# PHP : search for a string within a string

Tags: php, string, replace, find

I want to check whether a string is present in another string, and then take the appropriate action.  What is the best way to do this?

For instance; if the string 'europe' is present in 'europeisthebest', then do something.

```
if ( isIn('europe', 'europeisthebest') == true){
  //do something
}
```

Thank you a lot! I appreciate all of your answers and time spent helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (case sensitive), [`stristr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) (case insenstive), or [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
if (stristr('europeisthebest', 'europe')){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Hello John. Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I tried strpos previously but for some reason It wouldnt act correctly when I added ===true after the condition. Everything's good now. Thank you alot my friend.

Comment: @bornie That's because it doesn't return a boolean true; rather, it returns an integer if the string is found or a boolean false if it isn't. Using strpos to search for a string within a string can be accomplished like this: `if( strpos('blah', 'blah') !== false )`.

Comment: my string was like EX3.19 or EX7.99 and I wanted to search EX in the string... maybe because this might have caused the confusion... I dont know. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function strpos() if you wish to know the position of the substring inside the string